# masterKey in parse/config/global.json

Tags: parse-platform

Do I need to have my `masterKey` in `parse/config/global.json`?

It seems unsafe, and I don't want it in my git repository.

Can I safely remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I would just keep `global.json` out of the repo by putting it in `.gitignore`.

The file is easy enough to reconstruct with `parse generate`.

You can also backup the content of that file somewhere in your repo with the master key removed so you can recreate it in the future should your local copy become lost.